# Where is Magento code location to disable products?

Tags: magento, product

I am interested to know how can **Magento disable products**?

Where is the **code** which takes care of Product status i.e. eith **enable** or **disable** within Magento?

**Plz provide me code location for product disable in Magento?**

Answer (score 3):

A more effort into [googling your answer](http://www.google.com) might have helped you:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/195388/#t243282

`Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);`

also, you can run (on linux) the following grep command

`grep -rin -A2 -B2 "updateProductStatus" *`

to find out where instances of that piece of code might be called.

EDIT: on Magento 1.6.2.0, here are the places where you can find it. (e.g. the result of the shell command above)

```
electricjesus@quadsrv64:~/projects/magento/magento/app$ grep -rin -A2 -B2 "updateProductStatus" *
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php-172-     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php-173-     */
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php:174:    public function updateProductStatus($productId, $status, $store = null)
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php-175-    {
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php-176-        if (is_null($store)) {
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php-177-            foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php:178:                $this->updateProductStatus($productId, $status, $store->getId());
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php-179-            }
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php-180-            return $this;
--
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Observer.php-110-        $storeId    = $storeId > 0 ? $storeId : null;
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Observer.php-111-
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Observer.php:112:        $this->_getIndexer()->updateProductStatus($productId, $status, $storeId);
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Observer.php-113-
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Observer.php-114-        return $this;
--
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php-317-            if (isset($data['catalog_product_flat_status'])) {
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php-318-                $status = $data['catalog_product_flat_status'];
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php:319:                $this->_getIndexer()->updateProductStatus($productIds, $status);
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php-320-            }
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php-321-
--
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Status.php-198-     * @return  Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Status.php-199-     */
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Status.php:200:    public function updateProductStatus($productId, $storeId, $value)
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Status.php-201-    {
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Status.php-202-        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
--
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Status.php-106-     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Status
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Status.php-107-     */
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Status.php:108:    public function updateProductStatus($productId, $storeId, $value)
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Status.php-109-    {
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Status.php-110-        $statusAttributeId  = $this->_getProductAttribute('status')->getId();
```

Comment: I google the question...but didn't get exact code/file/function location in Magento...can any1 provide me the same?>>>

Comment: I updated my answer reflecting the code locations on Magento 1.6.2.0. Please read my answer thoroughly so you could be guided on how to obtain this information.