# how status of Product in Magento get changed/saved?

Tags: file, magento, status, product

I am eager to know **how status of Product in Magento get changed/saved**?

Requirement-:

Suppose there are existing products which are enabled in Magento...Now If **admin Disable** particular product from Backend then I need to catch that particular product's Id through code in Magento file system?

So from **where Can I get disabled product's id in Magento code**? What is the file location & function name for the same? how Can I get that particular id?

Please guide me...

Comment: how many questions will you ask on the same issue?

Comment: I am not getting required answer....I need code location for the same in Magento??

Comment: Sam, you are obviously new here. You should google this prior to asking them on here. Also try to ask one specific question not a multitude of questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is Magento code location to disable products?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847929/where-is-magento-code-location-to-disable-products)

Answer (score 2):

I think the down voting here is a bit unfair.  The op is only asking one question - how to get the product id and status of a product after it has been saved.

@Sam - in Magento, instead of finding the exact point in code where a product is being saved, you would typically hook into an event by creating a custom module and use the Magento event/observer facility from within that module.

Have a look through this tutorial which will guide you through the process of creating a module with event/observers: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Specifically related to your question: the event you are looking for is `catalog_product_save_after`.

The xml for your event would look similar to this:

```
<events>
  <catalog_product_save_after>
    <observers>
      <yourmodule>
        <class>Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
      </yourmodule>
    </observers>
  </catalog_product_save_after>     
</events>
```

Your observer is going to look similar to this:

```
class Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer 
{
    public function catalog_product_save_after($observer)
    {
        $product = $obvserver->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $productStatus = $product->getStatus();
        $productId = $product->getId();
    }
}
```

Note - code is untested

Comment: The down voting is justified.  Asking the same question again on SO is a behaviour that the community views as unacceptable.  If the OP is not happy with the answers he got, he should should EDIT his original question.